# react native base64 image upload fail with status code 400

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I want to upload my image as base 64 to the server, after user pick image it stores as base64 in state and then I call upload function but it give me this error: `request failed with status code 400`.
I need to first call an API and it takes user id and respond with an upload name id, then I call upload image API

here is my implementation:

```js
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true
    });

    setImage(result)
  };

 const uploadImagetoServer = async (userId) => {
    
    let uploadId;

    try {
      const response = await axios
        .post('URL', {
          "id": userId
        });
      console.log('id res', response.data);
      uploadId = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios
        .post('ANOTHER_URL', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },

          "fileName": uploadId,
          "fileBase64String": image.base64,
          "folderName": "Users",
          "fileExtension": ".jpg"

        });
      console.log('upload res', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }

  const allowAccess = async () => {
    if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
      } else {
        pickImage()
        .then(() => {
          uploadImagetoServer(userData.id)
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

anyone can help me with this? ty

Answer (score 0):

you need to add contentType in headers

```
'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;`,
```

here is an example

```
npm install --save form-data

import FormData from 'form-data'

let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', file, file.name);

return (dispatch) => {
axios.post(URL, data, {
  headers: {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
  }
})
  .then((response) => {
    //handle success
  }).catch((error) => {
    //handle error
  });
};}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but our api accepts json

Comment: i mean i need to send request as json string

Comment: you can pass your json object in body.

Comment: if you gonna pass the image in base64 within the body then you shoud add      'Content-Type': 'application/json'      in header, and if you pass in formData then 'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data;' hope so it will solve your problem